# SQL - Select in complex field

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table **TabCustomer** containing a number of fields.

One of these fields is a complex one named **externalUser**:

```
{"id":123,"companyID":12,"name":"Paul","surname":"Smith",...}
```

How can I select all the rows of this tab containing *Paul* as **name** in **externalUser**?

Conceptually,

would be something like `SELECT * from tabCustomer WHERE externalUser.name="Paul";`

This should work on sqlite as well and I cannot use PL/SQL or similar

Comment: I don't see anything about an `IN` operator in your question. If you want to check if a column contains a value then you can do something like `name LIKE '%Paul%'`.

Comment: True, just changed the title. thansk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach would be

```
SELECT * from tabCustomer WHERE externalUser LIKE "%Paul%";
```

If you want to ensure it's an exact match on name, try

```
SELECT * from tabCustomer WHERE externalUser LIKE '%"name":"Paul"%'
```

Not terribly efficient - ultimately you really need to break this apart into more tables.

Comment: "Not terribly efficient" and potentially incorrect.  OP is specifically wanting to check the `name` entry.  Perhaps `LIKE '%"name":"Paul"%'`?

Comment: @PaulDixon, Thanks but it does not work on my DB Browser for SQLite; do you know anyother solution?

Comment: now it works with your second solution thanks, will accept soon

Comment: @PaulDixon, When applying to id, shall I change anything? for instance, gaining all the id=123, can I do: SELECT * from tabCustomer WHERE externalUser LIKE '%"id":"123"%'?